# General way to quantize floating point numbers into arbitrary number of bins?

Tags: python, math, floating-point, arbitrary-precision, quantization

I want to quantize a series of numbers which have a maximum and minimum value of `X` and `Y` respectively into arbitrary number of bins. For instance, if the maximum value of my array is `65535` and the minimum is `0` (do not assume these are all integers) and I want to quantize the values into `2` bins, all values more than `floor(65535/2)` would become `65535` and the rest become `0`. Similar story repeats if I want to quantize the array from any number between `1` to `65535`. I wonder, is there an efficient and easy way to do this? If not, how can I do this efficiently for number of bins being powers of `2`? Although a pseudocode would be fine but Python + Numpy is preferred.

Comment: Yes sure, sorry my bad.  Updated my post

Comment: It seems like the obvious thing to do, which you mention, is floor(x/(range/nbins)). Why is that not a desirable solution? It seems easy and, as for efficiency, I don't see how you would improve on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the most elegant solution, but:

```
MIN_VALUE = 0
MAX_VALUE = 65535
NO_BINS = 2   

# Create random dataset from [0,65535] interval
numbers = np.random.randint(0,65535+1,100)

# Create bin edges
bins = np.arange(0,65535, (MAX_VALUE-MIN_VALUE)/NO_BINS)

# Get bin values
_, bin_val = np.histogram(numbers, NO_BINS-1, range=(MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE))

# Change the values to the bin value
for iter_bin in range(1,NO_BINS+1):
    numbers[np.where(digits == iter_bin)] = bin_val[iter_bin-1]
```

---

**UPDATE**

Does the same job:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# or bin_labels = [i*((MAX_VALUE - MIN_VALUE) / (NO_BINS-1)) for i in range(NO_BINS)]
_, bin_labels = np.histogram(numbers, NO_BINS-1, range=(MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE))

pd.cut(numbers, NO_BINS, right=False, labels=bin_labels)
```

Comment: I don't have time to test this now will test this soon. Before I do that, I just want to make sure: does your code work with arbitrary number of bits? What if I want 63 bins? What if the values of the main array are float?

Comment: You can define the number of bins using the `NO_BINS` variable. It works with floats, as well. Obviously I haven't written extensive tests.